# Programmatically move or activate split keyboard on iPad (ios5)

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ios5

i'm wondering if its possible to force the keyboard to use the new split function (iOS5), and if its possible to set it to a given position.

Comment: Still NDA, try forums - http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Reference: [iOS 5: Any way to prevent keyboard splitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809997/ios-5-any-way-to-prevent-keyboard-splitting)

Although, it is possible to turn it off on YOUR device. Check out this post: [Turn Off & disable Split keyboard feature on iPad](http://www.iguiding.com/disable-ipad-divide-split-keyboard-ios5/).