# iOS 5: Any way to prevent keyboard splitting?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, split, ios5

The new splittable/movable keyboard in iOS5 is not suitable for the UI of an app I'm currently working on. We'd like to fix it in place at the bottom as was the norm pre-iOS 5. Any thoughts on how to do this and prevent the user from moving/splitting the keyboard?

Cheers!

Comment: You could roll-your-own keyboard. I wouldn't recommend it, as you usually want to stick with native, familiar controls, but that's a potential option.

Comment: Split keyboard is one of my favorite iOS 5 features for iPad. If one of the apps I use somehow blocked it, it would get a b ad review. you should adapt to the system you are targeting, not cripple it.

Comment: Just don't. The user has split the keyboard because he/she *wants* it split.

Comment: guys, Rich wants to know how to prevent it, not whether or not he should do it. I can think of examples where it's important to do. I also would like to know whether it's possible to prevent the splitting or not. ATM @DA's solution looks like the only feasible solution

Comment: As a helpful note, it is possible to turn off keyboard splitting/undocking as an ipad user in the settings.  Granted this doesn't help app developers, myself included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to prevent keyboard splitting. The most you can hope for is to either

1. Provide user feedback after the user splits the keyboard
   notifying them that this is not the best user experience and is not
   supported by your app.
2. Roll your own keyboard

IMO, #1 is the best approach. Rolling your own keyboard -- with localization support -- is almost never practical.