# Can i prevent keyboard from spliting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

User can split keyboard in my app.
I want to prevent keyboard split from user how can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the option of splitting keyboard from user. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809997/ios-5-any-way-to-prevent-keyboard-splitting) for other option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, **No** you can't do this through code.

This feature is introduced in **iOS 5** and greater.

If user don't want this feature then they can turnoff it from the settings App.

[image: Split keyboard]

As far as I know, till now (16th January-2013) apple didn't provided any API for doing this.